# Flutter and Firebase | How to show different page dynamically whenever user email is verified or not?

Tags: firebase, flutter

I have this scenario in my app which the user logged in and then the app will check the `userSnapShot` data (via `StreamBuilder` from `ScreenHandler.dart`) if data exist. If yes, then it will check if the email is already verified or not. If verified, the user will redirect to `HomeScreen`, else, he will redirect to `VerifyEmail.dart` page.

Logically, once the user already logged in successfully before, he will never to do login again, unless he signed out. The problem is I can't call for `isEmailVerified()` inside my `ScreenHandler.dart` without doing any authentication process. Any idea on how to resolve this issue? Thanks!

Comment: Any code to go along with the question, to see what you have tried so far, and what are you struggling with? Fetching something from StreamBuilder has loads of tutorials on how to do it, pushing new screens with Navigator too. Please try to be more specific with the question.

Answer (score 0):

Below is my current code. Though I managed to resolve my issue after using this. Still, I really doubt how elegant this code actually. Is it okay to call the `isUserVerified` method inside `StreamBuilder`? I tested it and found out that the `isUserVerified` method continuously called inside of the `StreamBuilder` which is I'm concerned of. Do you think this kind of solution can lead to any performance or leak issues? Do you have any recommendations or examples on how to do it correctly? Thank you.

```
import 'package:adalley/user_interface/screen_home.dart';
import 'package:adalley/user_interface/screen_login.dart';
import 'package:adalley/user_interface/screen_verifyEmail.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class ScreenHandler extends StatefulWidget {
  _ScreenHandlerState createState() => _ScreenHandlerState();
}

class _ScreenHandlerState extends State<ScreenHandler> {

  final FirebaseAuth _fireBaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  FirebaseUser currentUser;
  bool myEmail;

  isUserVerified() async {
    currentUser = await _fireBaseAuth.currentUser();
    setState(() {
      myEmail =  currentUser.isEmailVerified;
      print(myEmail);
    });
  }

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }


  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged,
      builder: (ctx, userSnapShot) {
        if (userSnapShot.hasData) {
          isUserVerified();
          if (myEmail != null && myEmail == true) {
            return HomeScreen();
          } else {
            return VerifyEmail();
          }
        } else {
          return Login();
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it because isUserVerified() calls setState() which causes a rebuild which calls isUserVerified()...repeat over and over?

Comment: Hi Robert, Thank you for your reply. I already solved this issue by changing the way I approached it. I removed the streambuilder and just use a typical navigator after checking the user auth/validity in the splash loading.